# How to control 'onchange' event for 'date' input widget?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor

I have date input like this:

```
<input id="filter_marker_bycreationdate" name="filter_marker_bycreationdate" type="date" value="@string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.FilterByCreationDate)" class="marker_list_list_filter_controll_input">
```

and I use its 'onchange' event like this:

```
$("#filter_marker_bycreationdate").on("change", function (event) {
             
            });
```

It works perfect when the date is selected from the drop menus of the control (day, month and year).

However, there is a problem when user tries to manually type these three numbers. In this case, day and month can be typed ok, but the problem is with the year because it comes last. As soon as the first digit of the year is typed (for example 0004) it is immediately recognized as date change and 'onchange' is called not allowing me to complete the year number, like for example 2014.

What would be the solution here?

Is there a way to have 'onchange' called only in case the drop-downs of the date widget are used, and then in case of manual typing to call 'onchange' on ENTER once the date is completed?

Or, another solution...to somehow disable any typing for these date textboxes and allows only drop-downs to be used?

Comment: What's inside your event handler?

Comment: @ynzen it calls a function that send request to the controller

Comment: Which kind of widget or plugin are you using to create the DatePicker? Can you post the Enough code or create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem, it will be helpful for us to help you solve the problem.

Comment: @ZhiLv it is just built-in input date control from ASP and I already provided the tag for this in description. Simply copy-paste this in your HTML: <input id="filter_marker_bycreationdate" name="filter_marker_bycreationdate" type="date" value="@string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.FilterByCreationDate)" class="marker_list_list_filter_controll_input">

Comment: Hi @Ivan, Please check the sample in my reply, the code works well on my side (using chrome browser).

Answer (score 1):

According to your description and code, I have created a sample using the following sample code, it seems that everything works well on my machine. Please check it.

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    [BindProperty]
    //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime FilterByCreationDate { get; set; }
    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGetAsync()
    {
        FilterByCreationDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
 
<input id="filter_marker_bycreationdate" name="filter_marker_bycreationdate" type="date"
       value="@string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.FilterByCreationDate)" class="marker_list_list_filter_controll_input">


@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    $(function () {
        //there is no need to add the input onchange event
        $("#filter_marker_bycreationdate").on("change", function (event) {

        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Then the result like this:

[image]

If still not working, try to clear the browser data (cache, cookie and so on), then recheck whether the web page works well or not.

**Edit**:

> something like this...as you can see it triggers the event four times
> with the following values: 0002, 0020, 0202, 2020. But I want it to
> allow me to type all four numbers first and then trigger an event.

For this scenario, you could try to use the `onfocusout` event, it will be triggered when an input field is about to lose focus, code as below:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#filter_marker_bycreationdate").on("focusout", function (event) {
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

The result like this

[image]

Comment: But how do you change the year value? Do you scroll or type it number by number?

Comment: It seems like you're scrolling the value

Comment: No, the first time, I change the value via the drop menus. After that, I change the year value by typing the number by number.

Comment: ok, and if you set the break point when typing number by number, you'll notice that the event is fired on first number typed, not allowing you to complete the remaining three

Comment: Hi @Ivan, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByBaT.gif), perhaps you mean the browser debug behavior, after click the "Resume script execution" icon, typing the next number (there is no need to move the mouse and set focus on the input again).

Comment: @yes, something like this...as you can see it triggers the event four times with the following values: 0002, 0020, 0202, 2020. But I want it to allow me to type all four numbers first and then trigger an event.

Comment: Hi @Ivan, "But I want it to allow me to type all four numbers first and then trigger an event", For this scenario, you could try to use the `onfocusout` event, instead of using the `onchange` event. The `focusout` event will be triggered when an input field is about to lose focus, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfpUL.gif).

Comment: yes, this kindof solves the issue, but now it is annoying that you must explicitly clisk off the date-picker with the mouse in order to lose the focus. Any solution to this?